# Usar dos ngModel con el mismo nombre

Tags: html, angular

hola estoy haciendo un formulario utilizando angular el cual contiene los siguientes datos

```
<form >

  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombres: "
     [(ngModel)]="nombres" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="nombres"><br>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos: "
     [(ngModel)]="apellidos" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="apellidos"><br>

  <input type="email" placeholder=" Correo: "
     [(ngModel)]="correo" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="correo"><br>

  <label> Necesitas Servico (de mesero) </label> <br>

  <mat-radio-button [(ngModel)]="servicio" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
    name="servicio" value="si"
    (ngModelChange)="servicio= $event">Si</mat-radio-button>

  <mat-radio-button [(ngModel)]="servicio" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
    name="servicio" value="no"
    (ngModelChange)="servicio= $event">No</mat-radio-button><br><br>

  <button class="btn-guardar" type="submit" (click)="enviarmail()">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Tengo dos ngModel con el mismo nombre, cuando envío los datos con la función enviarmail() el campo de servicio se envía como undefined.

Como puedo resolver esto.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que agrupar los radio button en un [radio group](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview#radio-groups) y definir el ngmodel en el grupo, algo asi:

```
<mat-radio-group
  [(ngModel)]="servicio"
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
  (ngModelChange)="servicio=$event"
  name="servicio">

  <mat-radio-button value="si">Si</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="no">No</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```